# Why there are no contents listed in the configuration of the Web Content Display of Liferay 7.0?

Tags: liferay-7

I just migrated from Liferay 6.2 to Liferay 7.0.  So far Everything looks great. The site's theme still needs a couple of adjustments, but in general, everything looks great.

But now I have a problem.  The content of a page was expired, this page is using a Web Content Display, so I went to Configuration in order to select another web content, but in the list of contents, there are no contents listed. In the Web Content section of the site, there are many web contents available.  This is also happening in every page of the site that is using a Web Content Display.

So how can I figure out what is happening, why there are no contents listed in the configuration of the Web Content Display?

Comment: A quick guess: Did you reindex your search index?

Comment: I tried making a groovy script and the contents showed up again.

`import com.liferay.portal.kernel.service.UserLocalServiceUtil
import com.liferay.journal.service.JournalArticleLocalServiceUtil


articles = JournalArticleLocalServiceUtil.getJournalArticles(1,999999)
out.println(articles.size());

for( i=0; i<articles.size();i++){
    
    article = articles[i]
    out.println("Article " + i + "Titulo --" + article.getTitle() + "--");
    JournalArticleLocalServiceUtil.updateJournalArticle(article)
}`

Comment: Bad news,  after a full search re-index, the original problem happens again and the web contents disappeared again.

Answer (score 0):

My problem was solved.  Honestly, there was no problem.  The full search re-index toke several hours to finish.  So after the re-index process finished, all web contents were available again.  The first time I run the re-index process, I expected immediate results.  What I didn't know was that I have to wait until the process finished.